# Как выбрать узлы между элементами, если они вложены в разных родителей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне необходимо собрать массив из узлов, которые находятся между двумя элементами-метками, находящимися в разных родителях. Допустим, мне нужны параграфы.

```
<p>Первый <span class="before"></span>параграф с каким-то текстом</p>
<p>Второй параграф с каким-то текстом</p>
<p>Третий параграф с каким то текстом</p>
<p>Четвертый параграф <span class="after"></span> с каким-то текстом</p>
```

В результате мне нужно получить массив из второго и третьего параграфов. Если элемент не полностью находится между метками - он исключается. `nextUntil` из Jquery не помог - узлы-метки при такой дислокации тупо не видят контент между собой.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно попробовать следующую конструкцию :

```js
function findNodesBetweenElements(selector, startNode, endNode) {
    let paragraphs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartAfter(startNode);
    range.setEndBefore(endNode);
    let result = paragraphs.filter((item) => { return range.intersectsNode(item) });
    return result
}
let p = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
result = findNodesBetweenElements('p', p[0], p[p.length - 1]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<p>Первый
<span class="before"></span>
параграф с каким-то текстом</p>
<p>Второй параграф с каким-то текстом</p>
<p>Третий параграф с каким то текстом</p>
<p>Четвертый параграф <span class="after"></span> с каким-то текстом</p>
```

Функция  принимает в параметры сss селектор  и две ноды, между какими происходит поиск, для примера я добавил первый и последний параграф, при желании можно бросать туда любые ноды. Но ,например, если нода искомая лежит внутри исключаемой то она будет включена в результат.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо, интересное решение. Поэкспериментируем с гибкостью оного